# null values while changing data type from string type to integer type in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

i have a table that contains a column of numbers like (959, 1189...) when i check the column type i find it string type so i changed the type of column to integer type the problem is that when the column becomes integer type it shows null values that doesn't existed before instead of other values ( every number > 999 , for exemple 1232) this is how i'am changing the data type any help? : ```

```
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    IntegerType
)
dfnumber2 = dfnumber \
  .withColumn("Offres d'emploi" ,
              dfnumber["Offres d'emploi"]
              .cast(IntegerType()))   \
 
  
dfnumber2.printSchema()
```

Comment: there could be some values that are comma separated (e.g., `300` and `3,000`). instead of overwriting the column, create a new column and filter a few records where the new column is null - then check what the actual values were in the input dataframe. you could also try using `bigint` or `double` datatypes. if the column does contain commas, remove them before casting.

Answer (score 0):

The values are too big for the `int` type so PySpark is trimming, perhaps try to cast it to `double` type

```
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    DoubleType
)
dfnumber2 = dfnumber \
  .withColumn("Offres d'emploi" ,
              dfnumber["Offres d'emploi"]
              .cast(DoubleType()))   \
 
  
dfnumber2.printSchema()
```